# Реализация функции at для char C++

Tags: c++, строки, vector, at

Помогите ,пожалуйста, реализовать близкую реализацию функции `at()`. У меня существует класс для хранения массива типа `char` и мне нужно реализовать `at()`. Понял, что настоящий `at()` ловит исключения. Именно с этим я и не могу справиться, помогите пожалуйста.

Код:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
const  int LIMIT = 100;

class TCharArray
{
private:
    char element[LIMIT];
public:
    TCharArray();
    ~TCharArray();

    char& at(int n)
    {
        if (n < 0 || n >= LIMIT)
        {
            std::cout << "Error index!";
            exit(1);
        }
        return element[n];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не имеет смысла объявлять параметр функции `at`, как имеющий знаковый целочисленный тип.

"Настоящая" функция `at` не "ловит" исключения, а выбрасывает исключение, если указанный индекс выходит за пределы допустимого диапазона индексов.

Также лучше объявить константу `LIMIT` как член класса, так как это является характеристикой класса. Вы можете написать отдельную функцию-член класса, которая будет возвращать значение этой константы, как, например, `max_length` или `capacity`.

В вашем классе функция `at` может быть реализована, как показано ниже

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>


class TCharArray
{
private:
    static const size_t LIMIT = 100;
    char element[LIMIT];
public:
    TCharArray()
    {
        std::fill( element, element + LIMIT, char() );      
    }

    const char & at( size_t n ) const
    {
        if ( n >= LIMIT ) throw std::out_of_range( "Invalid index" );
        return element[n];
    }

    char & at( size_t n )
    {
        if ( n >= LIMIT ) throw std::out_of_range( "Invalid index" );
        return element[n];
    }
};  

int main() 
{
    TCharArray s;

    try
    {
        s.at( 100 ) = 'A';
    }
    catch ( std::exception &e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Invalid index
```

Comment: спасибо большое , стало понятно(про выбрасывает исключение). Можно вопрос, если в дальнейшем я хочу унаследоваться от моего класа 'TCharArray' и унаследованный класс будет предназначен для string, то лучше будет использовать шаблонный удач и метод?

Comment: @NikitaGusev Не совсем понятно, как вы собираетесь наследовать этот класс, и что собираетесь сделать шаблонным параметром. Лучше спросит это в отдельном вопросе, когда вы предоставите некоторую реализацию вашего нового класса, наследующего данный класс.

Comment: понял вас , но постараюсь последний раз обьяснить. Мой класс TCharArray- родительский класс, и мне нужно создать производный от него пользовательский класс String для хранения символьных строк , и перегрузить операторы +,<<,= и т.д. Для того чтобы , наследоваться от родительского стоит ли делать его шаблонным ?

Comment: @NikitaGusev Так не ясно, что вы собираетесь объявить шаблонным параметром?

Comment: сам класс и метод at в нем. Так как в наследованном классе собираюсь пользоваться методом родительского.

Comment: @NikitaGusev Я не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. Лучше сформулируйте эту задачу в новом вопросе, детализировав его примером реализации производного класса.

Comment: понял , спасибо ещё раз !